# Android Studio Access Denied Error on local app folder

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am in a world of trouble.  In a position of inheriting an Android App in Java with a team of C# .Net developers.

I am getting an (Access Denied) error to the projects root app folder *C:\Users\user.name\Development\theproject\app*

The project builds, cleans and rebuilds no problem but on debug or run, it fails at this step `app:transformDexWithInstantRunDependenciesApkForDebug`.

In the research so far I am getting lost in setting application permissions in the manifest.xml file but this feels more like a local machine folder permission issue more than an application issue.

I have tried running Android Studio in Adminstrator mode and both it and the emulator appear to be running under my username.  I have administration priviliges to my machine.

Any help greatly appreciated.  I had never heard of gradle until yesterday.

Comment: Did you enable multidex in gradle file?@K7Buoy

Comment: I wish I knew what that meant @Dhanshri.  :-(

Comment: I have found it ... will test.  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

Comment: Sorry @Dhanshri but that hasn't worked.

Comment: On a clean vanilla project with HelloWorld activity ... everything runs fine.

Comment: Issue sovled?@K7Buoy

Comment: No @Dhanshri I am afraid it is not.

Comment: Disable instant run and try again also just go and delete the build folder in your app folder. invalidate cache and clean your project then Rebuild...@ K7Buoy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183547/discussion-between-k7buoy-and-dhanshri).

Answer (score 1):

This is done as you have used multilibrary and the methods exceed the limits.

Modify your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

include this in application class :

```
public class YouApplication extends Application {

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}

}
```

Add this class name to the manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
   <application
       ...
       android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
       ...
   </application>
</manifest>
```